# Is it possible to execute a while loop in the background?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

I am creating a shell script and want to execute a certain while loop in the background. Normally, I would create a new `watch.sh` file containing:

```
while true; do ...; done
```

Then, in my main shell script, I would do:

```
nohup watch.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

My question is if this could be done without introducing a `watch.sh` file? That is, is it possible to directly run a certain while loop in the background? Would something like the following work?

```
while true; do ...; done &
```

This is a shell script, but I can move on to bash if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sh-like shells (including bash/zsh) let you use any block (compound command) the same way as a regular command, automatically starting a subshell process if necessary – it can be used as part of a pipeline, put into background, redirected, and even has its own 'exit code' and can be used in conditions.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. And would I need `while true; do ...; done &` or `(while true; do ...; done) &`. I am not sure if there is a difference?

Comment: There isn't any. A background job is _always_ a separate subshell process so the `( )` would be redundant.

Comment: Appreciate your answer grawity.